# How to open an URL on android app background click?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This code opens an URL on Xamarin :

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("http://www.website.com/"));
```

I'm new to Xamarin.
Could you explain how can I open an URL when I click the background on android app?

**Update**

I try in Xamarin.Forms on Visual Studio.

Comment: click the background ? Is it some button within the layout ?

Answer (score 2):

1.) Create a new Xamarin.Android application. The project template will create a single activity named Activity1 (MainActivity.cs), which contains a button.

2.) From the button.Click handler in MainActivity.cs, create a Uri and an Intent.

```
intent.button.Click += delegate {
   var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse ("http://www.xamarin.com");
   var intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionView, uri);
   StartActivity (intent);
};
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: this for Xamarin.Android

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `TapGestureRecognizer` to any control. In this case, let's say that your main container is a StackPanel. When it is tapped, you can do whatever you want, for example, opening a URL. Have a read how to do it [here](http://blog.falafel.com/adding-tapped-event-gestures-xaml-control-xamarin-forms/).

Basically:

```
var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => {
  // your code goes here
};
stackP.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
```

More info about GestureRecognizers can be found on the [official documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/gestures/).